# A single button that fires two commands in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, jupyter

I want to call a function and then destroy the window.

```
def open_window():
```

So this is a function

```
window=Tk()
```

This is the window.

```
b1=Button(window, text="Submit", width=12, command=open_window)
```

So I want to call the function open_window and destroy the window at once because I have toplevel widget in open_window function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call multiple functions using `lambda`:

```
b1=Button(window, text='Submit', width=12, command=lambda:(window.destroy(), open_window()))
```